# PHP syntax question: global $argv, $argc;

Tags: php

So I have a PHPUnit test, and found this code within a function.

```
global $argv, $argc;
echo $argc;
print_r($argv);
```

I understand what these variables represent (arguments passed from the command line), but I've never seen this syntax before:`global $argv, $argc;`

What specifically is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `global` keyword tells PHP to use the global scope version of a variable and make it visible to the current scope as well, so that variables declared outside functions/classes can be accessed within them too.

Otherwise, trying to read/assign those variables would operate on a different local version of them instead.

Compare:

```
$foo = 1;

function test() {
    $foo = 2;
}

echo $foo; // prints 1
```

versus...

```
$foo = 1;

function test() {
    global $foo;
    $foo = 2;
}

echo $foo; // prints 2
```

Comment: thanks, that's helpful, but the thing that I am confused about is that those variables are already defined. I'm not defining them. Also, the comma separating $argv, $argc. I haven't seen that before.

Comment: it is just making the vars globals. By making it globals, you can use the variables in functions as Dav stated

Comment: Basically Andrew, PHP has done the `$foo = 1;` in the above examples automatically; the `global` keyword is just used like in the functions above to access the global variables PHP has defined in a scope that isn't already global.

Answer (score 3):

In languages like Java, they allow you declare multiple variables of the same type on one line separated by a comma.

```
int sum, counter, days, number;
```

Without an IDE to test the code, I would say its the same regards to PHP, it just declares those two variables as `global`. You could write them separately on two seperate lines,

```
global $argv;
global $argc;
```

Answer (score 2):

`argv` and `arc` are the parameters passed when running a PHP script from the command line. As far as I'm aware these variables should never appear using HTTP.

See: [argc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argc.php) and [argv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) entries in the PHP manual.

The others already explained what global means. The comma simply groups similar declarations.

For example, this line would declare a bunch of private variables for a class:

```
private $name, $email, $datejoined;
```

which is the same thing as writing:

```
private $name;
private $email;
private $datejoined;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `global` keyword makes the specified variables.. well, global variables, accessible from anywhere in that file.

Comment: Not exactly. `global $a` within a function `foo` doesn't automatically make `$a` refer to the same global within another function `bar`. Instead the `global` keyword more makes a given name refer to the global version within the scope which the `global` keyword is used.